# why compiler is saying Incomplete type error in this code?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>

class A 
{    
   A a;            

};             

int main()       
{       

A a;              
return 0;           
}
```

why compiler is saying "a" has incomplete type ?
but in java recursion occurs ..plz explain it.?

Comment: You cannot have an instance of a type as a member of the same type. It is an infinite recursion.

Comment: Because Java allows this declaration, and C++ doesn't.  They are not equivalent languages.

Comment: Well, C++ would allow an `A*` inside an `A`, which is basically the same thing as what Java allows.

Comment: Why downvoting? If the user is a beginner I suppose it's a perfectly valid question

Comment: @DavidKernin I agree. This is not completely trivial stuff either.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, `A a` means an object of type `A`, not a reference or pointer to some object that lies somewhere else. The definition of `A` must be known to make such a statement, which, among other things, means the size of `A` must be fully determined.

When you attempt to have an instance of a type as a member of the same type, you would get an infinite recursion. The language simply disallows this, stating that a data member of any type must be a *complete type*, meaning its definition must be available.

This, on the other hand, is allowable, and is closer to java semantics:

```
class A { A* a; };
class B { B& b; };
```

See this related post for more information: [When to use forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 2):

The two are not equivalent. When you named an object in Java, you're actually naming a reference, so the equivalent code in C++ is:

```
class A 
{    
   A& a;
};
```

Or, arguably:

```
class A 
{    
   A* a;
};
```

And these are both perfectly valid.

On the other hand, trying to store a *value* of type `A` is obviously not going to work. Java simply does not have syntax to even attempt this, but C++ does — and the *incomplete type* rule prevents you from falling into it.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you're asking for a member of the same type of the class it is in. This is not allowed since you need to know the size of the object to create the memory layout to allocate it and it could go something like this:

```
- what's the size of A?
  - it contains an object of class A.. what's the size of this object?
    - what's the size of A?
      - it contains.. bla bla bla
```

and you'd end up having an infinite recursion without any meaning. That's disallowed. You could solve the matter with a reference or a pointer but that would be a different solution than what you asked.

In Java that syntax is allowed since it doesn't instantiate the type (it's a **reference**), but if you try to instantiate then the behavior is the same

```
public class myClass {
   private myClass p = new myClass(); // Runtime error!!

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new myClass();
   }
}
```

One thing to notice: Java doesn't catch this at compile-time but only at run-time (thus exhausting the VM's memory unless this mechanism isn't detected before that) while C++ manages to catch it at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

If we go to the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) we can see that a class is not completely defined until the closing `}`, this is in section `9.2` *Class members* paragraph *2*:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing } of the classspecifier. [...]

and all non-static data members of a class must be complete, which is in paragraph *9*:

> Non-static (9.4) data members shall not have incomplete types. In particular, a class C shall not contain
>   a non-static member of class C, but it can contain a pointer or reference to an object of class C.

but as it says it can contain a pointer or a reference which would be closer to how Java does it.